# Twitter says I have XXX number of tweets and I don't have any...

Tags: twitter, tweet

I tried to delete all of my 300ish tweets and there are like 100ish left but Twitter says I don't have any tweets. How do I fix that?

Comment: Your title appears to say the opposite of the question body?

Answer (score 1):

This is and issue with Twitter not the client. The only way to fix this is to:

1. ( ***Did not say how long you have been waiting***) Most likely wait it out ( ***it may be experience lots of traffic, therefore making it lag)***
2. Send in a complaint letter to Twitter support.
3. Refresh the page (***if you haven't already done so***)

That's all you can really do, as I said before it's not a problem you can really control because there are so many Twitter users it can cause the servers to lag:(. **Hope this helps:)**